# Marvel comic with robot aliens and major superhero deaths

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics

When I was a kid there was this Marvel comic where they battled some robot aliens and most Marvel superheroes died, the first superhero to die was Spider-Man, Death's Head was there and they said that only way to save the Marvel Universe was to find a way to resurrect Professor X.

Alien robot species had laser guns that could shot everyone, the only one they were having trouble shooting down was Colossus because of his titanium body.

It was a very awesome issue of Marvel Comics and I couldn't remember what it was, hoping somebody could help me and know what I'm talking about.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply but its not days of future past, there was this alien robot species who had laser guns that could one shot everyone, the only one they were having trouble shooting down was colossus because of his titanium body. i can only remember bits and pieces of this thing, one specially death'shead turning himself into a bullet and killing every alien in a room.... please help me i really want to finish this issue:(

Comment: Perhaps you have  time-frame when you read this. We don't know when you were a kid.

Comment: There is not much material here to work on, but when you says "most marvel superheroes died", most often than not it's the Onslaught event. There where robot with lasers, but they were just Sentinels, not aliens. Apart from this, there are not many other occasion where most marvel superheroes died; maybe against some galactic like Thanos, or...Thanos, and maybe...Thanos, but in those cases there were no robots at all, as far as I can remember.

Comment: A time frame would definitely be helpful, as well as what country you were in, since Death's Head started out as a Marvel UK character that could help us narrow down which pool of issues to consider. Also, if you remember which version of Death's Head it was (there've been three with wildly different designs) that could also help narrow it down.

Comment: Sorry guys im 32 right now and i think i was around 12 years old when i saw that issue...im in California at that time and no its not the death's head 2 wild hunt. I just wish i could elaborate more but everything's a blur... but the version of death's head is just like the one in wild hunt.

Answer (score 8):

#### You are looking for: [**Death’s Head II – The Wild Hunt #4 (1992): 2020 Vision!**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Death%27s_Head_II_Vol_1_4)

In this story, the mystic entity Charnal has all but exterminated most of the life on Earth-9939. In his final battles against the superheroes of this world, Spider-Man, Daredevil, Doctor Strange and the Punisher all die in their final confrontation with Charnal. Charnal has components which can be traced back to an earlier version of Death's Head and the Avengers go back in time to 1992 to see if they can defeat him there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, I can find no trace of the X-men in this particular comic and no mention of Professor X or Colossus. I believe there are other Death's Head and X-men crossovers and I will look through them when I get a moment.

UPDATE: Having had a moment, I found a issues of **Death's Head Vol. 2** and in 1992 (lasting up to issue #16), the X-men do appear in this second volume of Death's Head. These two volumes are likely the series you are looking for when you are seeking a major crossover between the Death Head and Marvel characters.

[image]

The enemy are adaptable mechanized-organisms called Raptors whose abilities include power-adaption. The more you used your powers against them, the better they fought. Their abilities included self-repair making them formidable foes, getting better the longer you fought them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to check [*Mys-Tech Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mys-Tech#Mys-Tech_War_and_More).

They have aliens as enemies and some have laser guns.

[image: Mys-Tech Wars picture]